# Exception not caught in Task.Run wrapped method

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

New to async await integration in C# 5.  I'm working with some basic Task based methods to explore async await and the TPL.  In this example below I'm calling a web service with a timeout of 5 seconds.  If the timeout expires it should throw an exception so I can return false from the method.  However, the timeout never occurs, or maybe it does but the Task never returns.

```
public static Task<bool> IsConnectedAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (WSAppService.AppService svc = new NCSoftware.Common.WSAppService.AppService(GetServiceUrl(WebService.app)){Timeout = 5000})
            {
                return svc.PingB();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex.Message, ex, "IsConnectedAsync");
        }    
        return false;
    });
}
```

If you could please help with how to properly handle this so that if the timeout occurs or even better, an exception occurs, the Task does return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't use `Task.Run` if you're wrapping `async` services.  Since this is a service reference, you should be able to expose an `async` method (returning `Task`) directly from the service, in which case you could use:

```
public async static Task<bool> IsConnectedAsync()
{
    try
    {
         using (WSAppService.AppService svc = new NCSoftware.Common.WSAppService.AppService(GetServiceUrl(WebService.app)){Timeout = 5000})
         {
              return await svc.PingBAsync();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Logger.LogException(ex.Message, ex, "IsConnectedAsync");
     }    
     return false;
}
```

If you must wrap via `Task.Run` (again, this is not suggested, as it's turning synchronous code into async via the thread pool, which is typically better handled by the user at the top level), you could do:

```
public async static Task<bool> IsConnectedAsync()
{
    try
    {
       return await Task.Run(() =>
       {
         using (WSAppService.AppService svc = new NCSoftware.Common.WSAppService.AppService(GetServiceUrl(WebService.app)){Timeout = 5000})
         {
              return svc.PingB();
         }
       }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Logger.LogException(ex.Message, ex, "IsConnectedAsync");
         return false;
     }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately this is an old ASMX .net 2.0 web service so it doesn't have Task based async services available.  Only the older Begin... End... type services so I could use a FromAsync I suppose?  Not sure if that would be preferred over your second option above?

Comment: @Neal Yes, I'd wrap it in a FromAsync, then use the first method.

Comment: The other problem with your second example is that you can't return false in the exception as you can't convert from false to Task<bool> I don't believe.

Comment: Sorry, and in your first example, shouldn't the caller do the await'ing so it should be return svc.PingBAsync(); without the await?

Comment: @Neal In the second example, sinc eit's an async method, the compiler will turn the `return false` into a `Task<bool>`.  In the first example, I didn't have the caller do the awaiting because you have exception handling in place.  The await call will make the exception ahndling work.  (That's the problem with your original...)